# How to mint NFT in Magic Eden by rpc or web3

Tags: nft, solana-web3js

I want to know about mint method in Magic Eden.
In Candy Machine we can mint NFT by web3 like this.

```
await candyMachine.program.instruction.mintNft(creatorBump, {
  accounts: {
    candyMachine: candyMachineAddress,
    candyMachineCreator,
    payer: payer,
    wallet: candyMachine.state.treasury,
    mint: mint.publicKey,
    metadata: metadataAddress,
    masterEdition,
    mintAuthority: payer,
    updateAuthority: payer,
    tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
    clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
    recentBlockhashes: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RECENT_BLOCKHASHES_PUBKEY,
    instructionSysvarAccount: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
  },
  remainingAccounts:
    remainingAccounts.length > 0 ? remainingAccounts : undefined,
})
```

How can I do this in Magic Eden.